# Integer Hash to a String Value

Tags: java, hash

I want to compute Hash of a String, but the Hash value should be a number (long or integer).

In other words I want to compute integer hash of a string. 
Collusion resistance in not the concern.

Is there an way to convert MessageDigest of SHA-256 to a number.

I am using Java to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you post some code to help describe what you are looking for?

Comment: I guess you need to specify your requirements: Do you need to calculate the value outside of Java, or consistently between different versions of Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Sha Hash has 256 Bits e.g.

```
"364b7e70a9966ef7686ab814958cd0017b7f19147a257d40603d4a1307662b42"
```

this will exceed the range of long and integer.
You could use `new BigInteger( hash, 16 );` for a decimal representation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        digest.update("string".getBytes() );
        byte[] hash = digest.digest();
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger( hash );
        System.out.println( "hex:" + bi.toString(16) + "\r\ndec:" + bi.toString() );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to call hashCode() method. It is already implemented and does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Most obviously there is a `hashCode()` method on `String`

As for converting the MessageDigest to a number, you can either use `hashCode` again or take the `byte` array from the digest and compact this down to whatever size you want, integer, long or whatever with (say) xor.

```
public int compactDigest(MessageDigest digest) {
    byte [] byteArr = digest.digest();
    // +3 since conversion to int array with divide length by four.
    // and we don't want to lose any bytes.
    ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteArr.length + 3);
    bytes.put(byteArr);
    bytes.rewind();

    IntBuffer ints = bytes.asIntBuffer();
    int compactDigest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.limit(); ++i) {
      compactDigest ^= ints.get(i);
    }

    return compactDigest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

class `String` has a `hashcode` method, like any other Java class, which transforms the string into a number. See the [documentation](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) of this method for the exact algorithm it uses.

Answer (score 0):

every object in java has `hashCode()` method. You can override it and specify your own logic. Look at the [examples](http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please find it here: http://pastebin.com/j6Cffkcp;

I but it returns only string.

Answer (score 0):

Cryptographic hashes created using the JCE classes (MessageDigest in your case) are essentially a sequence of bytes (256 bits for SHA-256). If you wish to store and manage these are numbers, you'll need to convert these into BigInteger or BigDecimal objects (given the length of the digest).

It is not always that a cryptographic hash of String objects are computed, and it is often done for the purpose of one-way encryption of secrets. If you are using the hash for other purposes, especially to ensure some sort of uniqueness among the Strings (that would be important when storing these objects in a hash map), you're better off using the hash value computed by the [String.hashCode method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29).